# How to change pushbutton background color when its selected/pressed dynamically in webchat botframework

Tags: botframework, bots, adaptive-cards, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am using botframework webchat using react for designing our bot. We need to highlight the user selection which was chosen from the previous adaptive card. I tried many ways but found nothing. Is there any way to get it?

[image]

e.g.
I selected “Bank Key Request” and then selected “Change”, but there is no difference. All buttons are same after selection too.

Comment: can you show me the button code

Answer (score 0):

we can use a state for button color , then update that state whenever button is pressed

```
this.state = {

  buttonColor:'red'
}
```

then in Button Component, place buttonColor state in in style

```
<Button onPress={()=> this.setState(buttonColor:"Blue")} style={{ color:this.state.buttonColor}} />
```

If you are using react-native-adaptive-cards, you can customize styles as follows

```
  customThemeConfig = {
        input: {
            borderColor: "#000000",
            backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
            borderRadius: 4,
            borderWidth: 1,
        },
        button: {
            "ios": {
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: "#1D9BF6",
            },
            "android": {
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: "#1D9BF6",
            },
            "windows": {
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: "#1D9BF6",
            }
        }
    }
    
<AdaptiveCards themeConfig={customThemeConfig} payload={payload} />
```

so whenever the button is pressed, the state will change color will turn to Blue.

Comment: here we dont have any Button components. These buttons are coming from webchat itself dynamically.

Comment: can post code , weChat component does has styleoptions, i.e.
 <WebChat styleOptions={styleOptions} />

Comment: yes we have styleSetOptions but we dont have anything on click of pushbutton buttons.For suppose if we want the pushbutton color as blue on hovering I am acheiving this feature using this code .ac-pushButton.style-default.primary.style-positive:hover {
  background-color: #034ea1 !important;
  color: white !important;
}